# qlist.count by a condition in qt

Tags: qt, count, qlist

I have a Qlist of myStruct like `QList<myStruct> list`.

myStruct contains a bool parameter (active). i.e. I have `list[i].active`.

I want to count number of list elements that `active` parameter is equivalent to `true`.

I use `qCount`. But it needs a value to compare, not a condition.

what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You can write simple `for` loop. Or you can use `std::count_if` for OOP style.

Comment: Thanks. But I need a fast way to count. How can I use `std::count_if` for my problem?

Comment: What you mean by a "fast count"? What performance problems do you have in this case? `std::count_if` has same performance as simple `for` loop. Please, show some code of your attempts before posting additional comments.

Comment: My code performs several tasks in a limited time. Looping over all my list is time consuming. But if not exist another way, I should use simple loop. Thanks.

Comment: You want to count through all elements with `O(N)` complexity, but you want  lower than `O(N)`? Really? It's a magic. Once again: how do you measure performance? Why you think that `for` or `std::count_if` is slow?

Comment: You cannot count anything faster than `O(N)` as mentioned, unless the list is sorted or you do an incremental count as you modify the list. You can also do a parallel count with multiple threads, if you should really need it.

Comment: OK friends. So,  I had a silly question apparently! Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not want use simple loop as suggested before. You can support your own counter that will make appropriate increment\decrement when add\remove elements.

Comment: Thanks @stanislav888. That is a clever and cross-cut way. Nice.